# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from : Document is empty

Tags: php, curl, soap, dynamic, ntlm

I have check every configuration is perfect like, SOPA, CURL, XML, libxml in php.ini file. But I am getting issue. I don't know what is the issue. It's working on local machine but when i upload on server and check  then it's not working. I am trying to integrate dynamic nav api using NTLMSoapClient but it's not working in server.

Please see Below Code

```
$product = new NTLMSoapClient(PRODUCT_URL);
/*$params_d = array('filter' => array(

),
                  'setSize' => 2);*/
$result = $product->ReadMultiple();
$productData = $result->ReadMultiple_Result->WebItems;
```

Please help me if you know any solution

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Thanks. for now if you know solution then please help me

Comment: Can u provide any further information then "its not working". Logs, errormessages, anything?

Comment: Getting this message "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from "

Comment: Any luck @JiteshGondaliya? i am facing same issue

Comment: In my experience it should happen whenever you are calling wrong URL or maybe wrong auth user

Answer (score 0):

This error message is really unspecific and could just mean that curl returned false, luckily you can use **curl_error** to find out what exactly went wrong. In my implementation it looked like this.

```
        $this->buffer = curl_exec($this->ch);
        if (curl_errno($this->ch)) {
            $error = curl_error($this->ch);
            throw new Exception('CURL error: ' . $error);
        }
```